# panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not float64

Tags: go, python-requests, type-assertion

I am trying to convert this simple python function to golang, but facing issues with this error

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not float64
```

`python`

```
def binance(crypto: str, currency: str):
    import requests

    base_url = "https://www.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol={}{}"
    base_url = base_url.format(crypto, currency)
  
    try:
        result = requests.get(base_url).json()
        print(result)
        result = result.get("price")
    except Exception as e:
        
        return False
    return result
```

here is the golang version(longer code and more complicated code than should be)

```
func Binance(crypto string, currency string) (float64, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("https://www.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=%s%s", crypto, currency), nil)
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Println("Error is req: ", err)
    }
    
    client := &http.Client{}
    
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error in send req: ", err)
    }
    respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    var respMap map[string]interface{}
    log.Printf("body=%v",respBody)
    json.Unmarshal(respBody,&respMap) 
    log.Printf("response=%v",respMap)
    price := respMap["price"]
    log.Printf("price=%v",price)

    pricer := price.(float64)
    return pricer, err
}
```

so what am I getting wrong here? Previously i had the error `cannot use price (type interface {}) as type float64 in return argument: need type assertion` and now i tried the type assertion with `pricer := price.(float64)` and now this error

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not float64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's telling you in the error, `price` is a string, not a float64, so you need to do (presumably):

```
pricer := price.(string)
return strconv.ParseFloat(pricer, 64)
```

A better way would probably be to instead do

```
type response struct {
    Price float64 `json:",string"`
}
r := &response{}
respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
err := json.Unmarshal(respBody, r) 
return r.Price, err
```

> The "string" option signals that a field is stored as JSON inside a JSON-encoded string. It applies only to fields of string, floating point, integer, or boolean types.

https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal

Comment: why is golang so troublesome like this??? that is the part am trying to figure out. Why is code so much longer than python?

Comment: @uberrebu: go is statically typed, and the json decoder cannot guess what type you want. A string is going to be a string unless you specifically parse in some other way.

Comment: @uberrebu Go's designers made sure that people don't mix types at all, in Go, even 2 arrays with the same element types but different length are considered 2 different types. Interestingly, in one of the talks by Rob pike, he says "If you don't like the type system, them go program in python."

Comment: @MargachChris cool got it

Answer (score 3):

The error already tells you: price is a string. So it is probably coming from a JSON that looks like:

```
{
   "price": "123"
}
```

but not

```
{
   "price": 123
}
```

The first unmarshals as string. The second unmarshals as float64.

In your case, you have to parse it:

```
    pricer,err := strconv.ParseFloat(price.(string),64)
```

Comment: It's happening to me like this:
If I put price.(string) it says is a float64
If I put price.(float64) it says is a string
So wtf?

Comment: @Juanpa, ask a new question and show your code.